# How to create an HTML5 email contact form with an file image upload using mail() or PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, email

**I've deployed a website for a class project (not a CS class) and am  making a contact form that requires a user to provide their basic user info with a photo.** However, upon form submission, I get an error that is echo'ed by my if statement.

I'm using a tutorial from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYocypr0Xig . I have created a directory called "tmp_name" in the directory where the php file resides as per https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp . I have looked around for more than 10 hours and cannot find a solution or a more concise example to follow that specifies *why*, like the Youtube video does.

HTML:

```
<form action="betacontactform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="columns" style="width: 500px; ">
      <h3 id="intro-box-headers">User Details:</h3>
      * First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" required>
      Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe">
      * Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="jdoe@example.com" required>
      * County: <input type="text" name="county" placeholder="County" required>
      * State: <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" required>
    </div>
      <span>* At least 1 picture of your project must be uploaded:</span>
      <input type="file" name="attachment" placeholder="Upload Images (required):" required/>
<!-- TODO: multiple optional image file uploads -->
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <input style="margin-left: 0px;" class="submit-form-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['attachment'])) {
  // $message contents
  $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
  $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
  $county = $_POST['county'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];

  // image upload attachment
  // store some variables
  $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
  $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];

  // get the extension of the get_included_files
  $base = basename($file_name);
  $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

  // only these file types will be allowed
  $allowed_extensions = array(".png","jpeg",".jpg");

  // mail essentials
  $from = $_POST['email'];
  $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
  $subject = "New Client Alert!!";
  $message = "You have received an email from $firstName $lastName \n Location: $county $state";

  // things you need
  $file = $temp_name;
  $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
  $uid = md5(uniqueid(time()));

  // standard email headers
  $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
  $header .= "Reply-To".$replyto."\r\n";
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

  // declaring we have multiple kinds of email (i.e. plain text and attachment)
  $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

  // plain text part
  $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

  // file attachment part
  $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
  $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, "", $header);
  header("Location: /website/postformpage.html");
} else {
  echo "Error!";
}
```

I expect it to go through however I'm not sure why it outputs the error and where I messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you expect a submit post data?

isset($_POST['submit']) ?

take it off or just change the button to input

```
<button style="margin-left: ;" class="submit-form-button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit!</button>

to

<input style="margin-left:0;" class="submit-form-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Good catch, I've made the following change below but it still produces the error.

<input style="margin-left: 0px;" class="submit-form-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

Comment: The error is from the IF statement... } else {
  echo "Error!";
}

Comment: is your file betacontactform.php the same where your html is? then change action to action=""

Comment: Try also to print  -> print('<pre>'.print_r($_POST, 1).'</pre>'); and print('<pre>'.print_r($_FILES, 1).'</pre>'); |||  in both cases should have the data, it seems like the post data is not coming to your php file

Comment: the file betacontactform.php is in the same directory but I'm confident the action="betacontactform.php". I understand what you're getting at with the second comment but I don't understand the code: Try also to print -> print('<pre>'.print_r($_POST, 1).'</pre>'); and print('<pre>'.print_r($_FILES, 1).'</pre>');

Comment: That is to print what do you have in the post data and you can see if your form is submitting the data properly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you expect a submit post data

isset($_POST['submit'])

take it off or just change the button to input

```
<button style="margin-left: ;" class="submit-form-button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit!</button>

to

<input style="margin-left:0;" class="submit-form-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```